# How to combine a http->https redirect with a 404 redirect to /

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Let's say I have a website. mywebsite.com

I want http to always redirect to https:
- `http://mywebsite.com` to `https://mywebsite.com`
- `http://mywebsite.com/any-page-url` to `https://mywebsite.com/any-page-url`
- `http://subdomain.mywebsite.com` to `https://subdomain.mywebsite.com`

I currently have this working fine using the following in the `.htaccess` at the root of my server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Now, in my specific subdomain, let's say `/www/subdomain` I want all 404 to redirect to the root of that website. So for example, if `http://subdomain.mywebsite.com/ksjhskf` does not exist, redirect to `http://subdomain.mywebsite.com`.

For this, I added the following in a `.htaccess` in `/www/subdomain`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Now, the http to https redirect no longer works on my `subdomain` subdomain.

How can I make both work concurrently?

Comment: You need to add the http/https snipped in both .htaccess. You can also add both of your rules in the root htaccess and delete the htaccess on the subdomain directory.

Comment: @DayronGallardo I tried to do that and pages stopped loading all together :/ Could you share a snippet?